# include PHP codes in R

Tags: php, r, shiny

While a lot of tutorials and help materials available to execute R codes in PHP,
Is there a way to include php codes in R.  For example, can I include the following code in a shiny application and open the php info file?

```
 <?
php phpinfo(); 
?>
```

Comment: First you say you want to _execute R codes in PHP_, then _include php codes in R_. Which one are you trying to achieve? First one is pretty simple, the latter one would be more challenging AFAIK.

Comment: @Dencker The latter, include php codes in R

Comment: @Dencker I think they were saying that they have found lots of materials telling them how to include R inside of PHP but are not looking for that. They want to use PHP inside of R (and specificially it looks like inside of a shiny app).

Comment: Ah, I didn't read it closely enough.